# More than 5V from USB-A charger?

Tags: power, usb, charger, usb-c, usb-pd

I recently came across a USB charger (Xiaomi MDY-11-EZ) with the following specs:

> 5.0V=3A 15.0W 
> 9.0V=3A 27.0W 
> 12.0V=2.25A 27.0W 
> 20.0V =1.35A Max 27.0W 
> 11.0V=3.0A Max 33.0W Max

What confuses me about this is the fact that the charger has only a USB-A socket and comes with a USB-A -> USB-C adapter cable. Since the USB-A connector does not provide the necessary signals to negotiate any power delivery settings; how does the charger decide the output voltage?

As a side note: I also used this charger to power (/charge) a custom Li-ion-powered board which led to the destruction of the device after plugging in the USB cable. On the device I used the 5.1k resistors on the CC lines to get 5V with a PD-capable charger, which worked with no problems with other USB-C chargers...

Any ideas?

Best, Josh

Comment: Please contact the supplier of the device.

Answer (score 3):

The power supply uses Quick Charge protocol, that is communicated via the USB data pins.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. When I look into the datasheet of a QC2.0 charger IC (CHY100), I find the same voltage options as stated above: https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/328/chiphy_family_datasheet-269468.pdf
Unfortunately, I cannot see what happens when the D+/D- voltage does not match the 4 cases in the datasheet (Table 1). I would assume that it uses the "default" (5V) but I am not sure how it would react to floating D+/D- pins.
I guess that, depending on the input impedance of their measurement circuit, also measuring a voltage > 0V would be possible on floating pins!?

Comment: @MoTex_42 note it says it looks at the voltage **after** a power negotiation. That is just one step of the power negotation. Seems that first both devices agree to use Quick Charge and *then* the data pin voltage is read to determine the power voltage.

Comment: The voltage output must of course be 5V like with any other standard USB device, if the other device is not even connected and the pins float.

Comment: @user253751: With that it seems to be very unlikely that the charger "accidentally" enters the quick charge mode and sets the output voltage to a level > 5V... In this case something else must have caused the problem on my device. I'll try to investigate that further.
Thanks for clarifying that it is a QC device!